# Entity Framework incorrectly skips DB column

Tags: c#, entity-framework

**SOLUTION:**

There was a 2nd EDMX in the project that was not generating a visual diagram, so I wrongly assumed it wasn't in use. Updating this secondary EDMX allowed the new record to act as expected.

---

Apologies if I incorrectly name anything below, C# is not my strength!

I'm working on updating an older project built in C# .net. I've done the following on the project before without issue and a few similar projects, all without issue.

I'm looking at adding a new column to the database, then updating the EDMX to account for the new column. The column name is "ExternalURL" in this case. The column name is correctly recognized in the EDMX and the file updates without error. The class (category.cs) is also successfully updated with the new "ExternalURL" property.

Finally jumping into the code, and calling up category.ExternalURL returns a value with error, BUT it always returns null. I've tried manually setting some values in the DB and it still returns null. Attempting to save a value in the code, and saving it to the database returns success and the property is attached to the object, but it's never written to the database. Editing any other properties are fine, for example, category.name gets updated just fine.

I've done some further digging, and found a way to view the SQL statement the Entity framework is generating and it appears to be missing the new column completely on the insert/select statement. Here is an example.

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[CategoryID] AS [CategoryID], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[Position] AS [Position], 
    [Extent1].[CreatedOn] AS [CreatedOn], 
    [Extent1].[ModifiedOn] AS [ModifiedOn]
    FROM [dbo].[Category] AS [Extent1]
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[Position] ASC
```

As well here is a picture of the database records.

[Database Select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgmT5.png)

Additionally here is an example of how the records are returned.
[Returned Records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6drdR.png)

Lastly here is the EDMX.
[EDMX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUfuS.png)

On day 3 of googling this, so kinda at a lost and open to all suggestions. Please let me know if more details are needed!

Thanks!

Edit:

The code handling the select

```
List<Category> items = Global.DbContext.Categories.OrderBy(x => x.Position).ToList();

        grdData.DataSource = items;
        grdData.DataBind();
```

The code handling the insert

```
                Category category = null;

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCategoryID.Value))
                {
                    category = Global.DbContext.Categories.Find(int.Parse(txtCategoryID.Value));
                }


                category.Name = txtName.Text.Trim();
                category.ExternalURL = "Hello";

                Global.DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Edit 2:

The 3 times "ExternalURL" is in the EDMX.

```
        <EntityType Name="Category">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="CategoryID" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="CategoryID" Type="int" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Name" Type="varchar" MaxLength="50" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Position" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="CreatedOn" Type="datetime" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="ModifiedOn" Type="datetime" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="ExternalURL" Type="varchar" MaxLength="255" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
```

```
        <EntityType Name="Category">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="CategoryID" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="CategoryID" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
          <Property Name="Name" Type="String" MaxLength="50" Unicode="false" Nullable="false" FixedLength="false" />
          <Property Name="Position" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="CreatedOn" Type="DateTime" Nullable="false" Precision="3" />
          <Property Name="ModifiedOn" Type="DateTime" Nullable="false" Precision="3" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="SubCategories" Relationship="Self.FK_SubCategory_Category" FromRole="Category" ToRole="SubCategory" />
          <Property Name="ExternalURL" Type="String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="255" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
        </EntityType>
```

```
<EntitySetMapping Name="Categories">
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(FileSuppliesModel.Category)">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Category">
                <ScalarProperty Name="ExternalURL" ColumnName="ExternalURL" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="ModifiedOn" ColumnName="ModifiedOn" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="CreatedOn" ColumnName="CreatedOn" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Position" ColumnName="Position" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Name" ColumnName="Name" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="CategoryID" ColumnName="CategoryID" />
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
          </EntitySetMapping>
```

Comment: Show us your code please and the table structure in design mode inside of ssms. Also try using sql profiler while you're inserting/updating and check the generated sql.

Comment: My guess is, dll in your "bin" folder might be older version. it might sound silly but often times, its possible. So, I would manually delete all bin and obj folders and then give it a shot. Also, could you post the C# code where you are trying to retrieve.

Comment: @sam I have also reviewed this, the bin file in the website directory is being updated as well as the folders you mentioned.

Comment: Have you looked into the mapping code within the edmx? has the code been generated appropriately? can you share some of that code?

Comment: @sam That would make a lot of sense actually.

Comment: @sam Got back into the office today and tested your theory again just to be sure, and no dice :(

Comment: @ChrisWatts I've attached a picture of part of the EDMX in the original post, is there another section you want to see? Thanks

Comment: @Adrian, if you have *.tt files in the solution, could you right click on file in solution explorer and say "Run Custom Tool" (the sequence is first do it on file without context and then on .context.tt).  If this wont work, then right click on edmx file, select "Open With" and select "Select "Automatic Editor Selector (XML)" , then search for the new column name that you have added. Please update us what you notice.

Comment: @sam Sure, ran both suggestions. No clear indication of anything changed.I've had to manually add a record in the edmx file in the past so I have reviewed it and it does appear to be correct. I've updated the original post with the 3 references.

Comment: Thanks Adrian for updating the post with your observations. I see conflicting results. One of your (Returned Records) screenshots shows ExternalURL is null. Where as this line in edmx says ExternalURL nulls are not supported. <Property Name="ExternalURL" Type="String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="255" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
        </EntityType>. Are you sure, is it the only edmx file in your solution? or is the model with ExternalURL you are referring at expected Namespace (<Schema Namespace=.. )?

Comment: @sam Well I feel stupid, but I'm okay with that if it solves the issue.

There was a 2nd EDMX in the project, but the visual side of it was always blank and I never seen any classes within it. Used the steps you outlined to view the code of the EDMX, and confirmed it was being used. Updated the EDMX and the problem is fixed.

Thank you!

Comment: @sam is there a way to mark you as the correct answer?

Comment: @Adrian Glad you are able to solve the issue. I do not actually know how to mark as "Accepted answer" but instead you can click on the triangle to make the comment as obvious so other can use it.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into a few scenarios like this before.  My entity framework data is in a library (with a particular connection string) and my test app sometimes has a different one.  Are you pointing to the same database?  I would check that first.

Comment: If he was pointing to another table without that column, EF would throw an error because the column didn't exist when he would perform a CRUD operation.

Comment: Table reads as well. Error throws something like "column... not found or does not exist"

Comment: You are correct, I have just run a test on mine and it threw said error.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! They are the same DB, I have checked this as my project is set up in a similar fashion.

I have confirmed it's the same database as I can update the name (at the same time as updated the externalURL) and the name column gets updated without issue.